# Spark scheduler vs Spark Core?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm discovering Apache Spark for didactical purposes and I'm a bit confused on how scheduling of tasks is managed. I found out that Spark has 3 options for scheduling: Spark Scheduler, YARN Scheduler and MESOS. But then I've also read that the Spark Core manages the scheduling of tasks. So I think that I'm not getting the point here:

why do we need a scheduler below Spark Core if it manages the scheduling of tasks?

And then, what does it mean that these tasks are executed in parallel? Does it mean in parallel on more workers or in parallel on the same worker?

Comment: For the 1st do you not man Spark Stand Alone?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html

Comment: Total task in a stage is splitted across excecutors  in all worker nodes. If you have 32 task and 4 worker node and 2 executer each then. 8 task  executed at a time parallel ,

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple levels of resource management in spark.  First is the allocation of executors on instances. yarn/k8/mesos/local are all examples of this.  each exexcutor has the ability to process a certain number of tasks at once.  Inside the driver is a system to take execution graphs break them into task sets and then allocate those tasks to executors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have confused about the resource manager and the job scheduler. For Spark ,it can run stand alone , in other words, it have the resource(CPU\MEMORY) management and job(data pipeline\job flow) management.